# converting a matrix to a list

Tags: list, r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix `foo` as follows:

```
foo <- cbind(c(1,2,3), c(15,16,17))

> foo
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   15
[2,]    2   16
[3,]    3   17
```

I'd like to turn it into a list that looks like

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 15

[[2]]
[1]  2 16

[[3]]
[1]  3 17
```

You can do it as follows:

`lapply(apply(foo, 1, function(x) list(c(x[1], x[2]))), function(y) unlist(y))`

I'm interested in an alternative method that isn't as complicated.  Note, if you just do `apply(foo, 1, function(x) list(c(x[1], x[2])))`, it returns a list within a list, which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: See this question with more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819804/convert-a-matrix-to-a-list-of-column-vectors

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a cleaner solution:

```
as.list(data.frame(t(foo)))
```

That takes advantage of the fact that a data frame is really just a list of equal length vectors (while a matrix is really a vector that is displayed with columns and rows...you can see this by calling foo[5], for instance).

You could also do this, although it isn't much of an improvement:

```
lapply(1:nrow(foo), function(i) foo[i,])
```

Comment: Your `as.list()` method is perfect.  And also much faster than my method (0.847 s v. 2.45 s).

Answer (score 6):

```
library(plyr)
alply(foo, 1)
```

Comment: Is there any solution with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asplit` to split a matrix into a list.

```
asplit(foo, 1)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1 15
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  2 16
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  3 17
```