# sorting a matrix in r

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix like below but with `n` rows

```r
set.seed(123)
mt <- replicate(5, sample(1:3, 4, replace = TRUE))
mt
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    3    3    3    1    3
#> [2,]    3    2    1    2    3
#> [3,]    3    2    2    3    1
#> [4,]    2    2    2    1    1
```

To sort it row by row, I am using this code with the `order` function, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12077502/12685768):

```r
od2 <- order(mt[1, ], mt[2, ], mt[3, ], mt[4, ])
mt[, od2]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    3    3    3    3
#> [2,]    2    1    2    3    3
#> [3,]    3    2    2    1    3
#> [4,]    1    2    2    1    2
```

Is there any way to adapt this code to `n` rows?  I was not successful with the second version of that answer given as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077413#comment71029012_12077502).  I am not familiar with the `do.call` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do.call` needs *a `list` as arguments to the function call.* So you need to split the rows of the matrix into a list. The function `asplit` can do this by *split an array or matrix by its margins*.

```
mt[,do.call(order, asplit(mt, 1))]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    3    3    3
#[2,]    2    1    2    3    3
#[3,]    3    2    2    1    3
#[4,]    1    2    2    1    2
```

`asplit` is currently (4.2.3) doing this by selceting the slices and filling up the list an a `for` loop. Other options can be found at [converting a matrix to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471188) or [Convert a matrix to a list of column-vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819804).

---

Comparing some possible methods with a larger matrix:

```
m <- matrix(sample(0:9, 1e6, TRUE), 1e3)

bench::mark(
asplit = m[,do.call(order, asplit(m, 1))],
data.frame = m[, do.call(order, data.frame(t(m)))],
splitRow = m[, do.call(order, split(m, row(m)))],
lapply = m[,do.call(order, lapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) m[i,]))],
splitNrow = m[, do.call(order, split(m, 1:nrow(m)))],
apply = m[, do.call(order, apply(m, 1, identity, simplify = FALSE))],
tapply = m[, do.call(order, tapply(m, row(m), identity))]
)
```

Result

```
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 asplit      8.44ms  9.02ms     111.    19.25MB     73.8    30    20      271ms
2 data.frame  6.88ms  7.24ms     138.    15.47MB     80.3    36    21    261.4ms
3 splitRow   19.79ms 19.98ms      48.9   31.01MB     73.3    10    15    204.6ms
4 lapply      6.79ms  6.99ms     141.    11.57MB     33.8    54    13    384.2ms
5 splitNrow   8.36ms  8.55ms     117.     7.76MB     16.3    50     7    428.8ms
6 apply       7.53ms  7.74ms     128.    15.38MB     50.6    43    17    335.9ms
7 tapply     27.64ms 28.47ms      35.4   38.73MB    165.      3    14     84.7ms
```

The methods `data.frame` and `lapply` are the fastest and `splitNrow` allocates the lowest amount of additional memory but `asplit` is not so far behind and is more general and works also for arrays and allows easy to change the margin.

Comment: thank you for the ``asplit`` function didn't know about it

Comment: Amazing answer. Appreciate the completeness of multiple solutions with a benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607931/13460602) to sorting by rows with a bunch of `t`ranspose, you can do:

```r
t(t(mt)[do.call(order, as.data.frame(t(mt))),])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    3    3    3
# [2,]    2    1    2    3    3
# [3,]    3    2    2    1    3
# [4,]    1    2    2    1    2
```

Or, simpler (as per @Ronak Shah's comment):

```r
mt[, do.call(order, data.frame(t(mt)))]
```

Comment: indeed! i added it in my answer but feel free to add a separate answer if you feel like it

Answer (score 1):

An option with `split`

```
mt[, do.call(order, split(mt, row(mt)))]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    3    3    3
[2,]    2    1    2    3    3
[3,]    3    2    2    1    3
[4,]    1    2    2    1    2
```